# React prop types for custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a component that returns an object (color theme object), which has nested objects for certain styles.

```
let colorPalette = {
 bgColors: {
  main: 'red',
  default: 'pink',
  ...
 },
 textColors: {
  main: 'black',
  default: 'red',
  ...
 }  
}
```

This colorPalette object is stored inside a context, which is accessed, by doing this:

```
context.providerValue.colorPalette
```

So, since I am using the colorPalette a lot, it does not make sense for me to use a color by accessing the colorPalette this way so I created a custom hook.
Looks like this:

```
const useGetColors = () => {
  let context = useContext(CustomContext)
   return context.providerValue.color
}
```

usage looks like this:

```
let colors  = useGetColors()
backgroundColor: colors.bg.main
```

What I'm trying to do is for the available values to appear when I do

```
colors.
or colors.bg.
```

So the available options appear, but not sure how to do it considering this is not a component...

Answer (score 0):

If you just need autocompletion of the IDE, you could use [JSDoc type annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html). Both WebStorm or Visual Studio Code can understand type annotations and they subsequently provide suggestions.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   bg: {
 *    main: string;
 *    default: string;
 *   },
 *   text: {
 *    main: string;
 *    default: string;
 *   }
 * }} ColorTheme
 * 
 * Returns colors theme
 * @returns {ColorTheme}
 */
function useGetColors() {
 ...
}
```

Comment: does this work with .js files?

Comment: Yes. IDEs use Typescript under the hood to parse it, but it is a JS file with JSdoc annotations. Try it on your editor/IDE.